# Desplegar un docker en AWS con EC2

Tags: docker, aws, docker-compose, docker-machine

Estoy intentando desplegar un docker en AWS con EC2 usando los drivers que ofrece docker, es decir, realizando lo siguiente:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 aws-prod
```

y me he encontrado los siguientes problemas y no se como resolverlos:

- Aunque tengo el ~/.aws/credentials me salta este error cada vez que lo ejecuto:

  Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: amazonec2 driver requires AWS credentials configured with the --amazonec2-access-key and --amazonec2-secret-key options, environment variables, ~/.aws/credentials, or an instance role

Lo he hecho de dos maneras el archivo, mediante aws configure y manual, pero no termina de cogerlo. No se si tendré que hacer algo más.

Consigo rodear este problema haciendo exportaciones de cada una de las variables. El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me da un problema de SSH, como que ha intentado varias veces conectarse y tampoco ha podido.

Por otro lado, he encontrado otros tutoriales en los que hacen el siguiente comando:

```
docker-machine -D create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY     --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-a8e5cfcd --amazonec2-zone b test-instance1
```

Pero entonces me sale el siguiente error (tambien previamente he tenido que exportar las claves):

```
Error with pre-create check: "unable to find a subnet in the zone: us-east-1b"
notifying bugsnag: [Error with pre-create check: "unable to find a subnet in the zone: us-east-1b"]
```

¿Alguien sabe como se pueden resolver estas incidencias o que puede ser que este haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Hola MGs el error que sale en el mensaje indica que no tienes una subnet disponible en la zona **us-east-1b**, para chequear las subnets que tienes creadas tienes que entrar a la consola web de AWS  **Services -> VPC -> Subnets**.

En la instrucción que estas usando le estas indicando usar la zona **b** aquí: --**amazonec2-zone b** quizás podrías chequear primero que subnet y en que zona tienes disponible con la VPC que estas usando aquí: **--amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-a8e5cfcd**

En AWS siempre es necesario la implementación de una VPC por temas de seguridad en la nube, la relación de la configuración que tendrías que hacer en ese sentido sería:

- VPC
- Subnet (chequear las zonas disponibles)
- Security Groups - VPC (para habilitar los puertos a los que tiene salida tu aplicación)